# How can I enable command blocks on a single player world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying a map that is made with command blocks and it does not work. I think it is the command blocks, i have searched for answers but couldn't find any. So how do i turn them on?

Comment: Command blocks should already be enabled in singeplayer worlds. What map are you trying, and in what way is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are in 1.11 and the map was made for 1.10 or earlier?
1.11 changed a few command block things, so it is very likely that the map needs an update in that case (or you just play on an older version to make it work again)

Answer (score 0):

Open your world to LAN and click the option "enable cheats"

If you create a new world you can also enable cheats on default, so you won't have to open it to the LAN every time.

Comment: They're not asking about cheats, they're asking about command blocks...

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad

Comment: Cheats need to be enabled to get command blocks, this could be the issue

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox The command blocks should already be there

Comment: @QunSyBer I didn't realise, I see what you mean